# How to get a pointer to raw binary data in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I'd like to get a pointer to raw binary data of bytes, bytearray, or memoryview instance via ctypes and Python API.

For reading, `(c_char * len(b)).from_buffer(b)` works in Python 3. For writing, I used the following:

```
buffer = c_void_p()
length = c_ssize_t()
pythonapi.PyObject_AsReadBuffer(py_object(b), byref(buffer), byref(length))
```

However I found out that the code doesn't work in Python 2.7 with memoryview.

Comment: How about ctypes.string_at() ?

Comment: @mdurant That does the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, I use a Python buffer structure defined via ctypes and a Python API function PyObject_GetBuffer to get the buffer from arbitrary compatible object. My Python buffer structure object is then transformed to c_char array and created buffer object is relased using PyBuffer_Release. See https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console/blob/master/win_unicode_console/buffer.py.